# How can I import a single string line of text to multiple HTML files?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This may be a very silly question with a very simple answer, but here goes:

I'm creating a Movie Catalogue in HTML to come up on my Galaxy 3 Tablet to help me chose what movies to watch (not commercial or professional).

I currently have around 10x various HTML pages for lists, main menu, frames, etc, and will be soon creating a further 20x pages for individual genres soon. At the bottom centered on every page I have a small foot-note containing my name and the date I last updated my catalogue:

Gus Diaz - 16/02/2015

That's it! It's pretty simple! This little footnote helps me understand just exactly how badly outdated my catalogue might be.

**QUESTION:**
Is there a way to dynamically update every HTML file with one central file using "quite possibly" a .CSS file or a Javascript file? I tried looking into the (STRING) command but couldn't find any answers.

**IDEALLY:**
I'd like to simply open a central .CSS file with the following string:

"Gus Diaz - 16/02/2015" and manually change it, and that could then update all other 20-30x various HTML files dynamically with a special code (maybe?)...

I even experimented this code on my HTML files, but it didn't work:

CSS:

```
.string .update {
    "Gus Diaz - 16/02/2015"
}
```

HTML:

```
<string class="update"></string>
```

Any ideas? Any help? Thanks in advance, the help I've received earlier on from this forum was tremendous!

Gus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with CSS:

```css
.update:before {
    content: "Gus Diaz - 16/02/2015";
}
```

```html
<string class="update"></string>
```

Comment: And yes, @uʍopǝpısdn you do deserve a cookie! Thanks bro! What does the :before selector do? I haven't really been around .CSS that much to know what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Write the same code on all the pages you want to show the message:

HTML

```
<span class="update"></span>
<script src="update.js"></script>
```

And edit just one js file:

JavaSCRIPT (update.js)

```
document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "Gus Diaz - 16/02/2015";
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a global variable, let's say: `footnote` in one file and then just refer to it from everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Html File

```
<div id="footer1"></div>
```

javascript file

```
document.getElementById('footer1').innerHTML="Gus Diaz - 16/02/2015"
```

and add javascript file using script code in every HTML file u want

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to use CSS :before or :after selectors:

```
.update:before {
    content: 'Gus Diaz - 16/02/2015';
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/j81wrL1m/1/ for a working example